# How to make an internal hinged door harder to open

Tags: doors, child-safety

I have a one and half year old who often opens the internal hinged door which would give him access to the stairs and outside. The door is nonlockable and we wouldn't want to it be lockable. Its second latch (?)- hidden metal thing part of doors mechanism that joins the door to side that keeps a door shut- is broken.

[image]

Comment: It's unclear what you mean .. Please post pictures.

Comment: Why wouldn't you fix the 'second latch', if that normally holds the door closed?

Comment: The first latch works- one controlled by the handle- hence I wanted it harder to open. The second latch was removed.

Comment: what do you mean, an internal hinged door. why do you not want it to be lockable?  not enough info and not sure what  " harder to open"  means.

Comment: It is internal to the house- lockable on our side would mean that the parents upstairs couldn't get to their bathroom. Putting a keyed lock would mean needing locksmith.

Comment: Why would you need a locksmith to fit a simple internal door lock?

Comment: A locksmith can sell you a thumb-turn-both-sides deadbolt, or offer other solutions after seeing exactly what you're dealing with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Our solution was put a hook and tie a ribbon loop. Our child loves pulling the door ajar. He can pull ribbon off but his compulsiveness means he thinks of the ribbon as normal so he puts it back. We can take of the loop from either side of the door with some risk of him shutting door on our fingers.

Answer (score 1):

There are premade solutions for that situation, try searching the web for "toddler proof doorknob." Here's a [random one from Target.](http://www.target.com/p/safety-1st-grip-n-twist-door-knob-covers-3pack/-/A-14061587)

[This one](https://www.bedbathandbeyond.com/store/product/french-door-lever-handle-lock-by-safety-1st-reg/1014996389?skuId=14996389&utm_source=bingpla&utm_medium=cpc&utm_term=ProductType1%3Dbaby%20locks%20%26%20guards&mcid=PS_bingpla_nonbrand_baby_&creative=9338890494&device=c) is designed for your style handle. Keep in mind that it will only work if the door handles turn independently. ie, can you open the door without moving the interior handle?

In a worst-case scenario you would need to replace the lever with a conventional round knob and place a childproof cage on one side. That's a simple project you can do on your own.

Answer (score 0):

The best thing to do is fit a latch or lock up high. Anything to make the door take more force to open will make it more likely to shut on your small person and hurt them. It's also not likely to work very well.

As you need adults to be able to open the door from both sides, a bolt at the top isn't an option for you. A spline key bolt can be opened from both sides but needs a key. A normal door handle mounted unusually high is common in nurseries and other childcare settings and most doors (even hollow ones) have a suitable place. Alternatively you can sometimes find thumb turn both sides latches but these are rare. Fitting new a new door handle is a routine DIY job, but any carpenter or handyman could do it